# UINavigationController application crashed with error msg: 'Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

In my navigation application, when step as follows, the app always crashed with error message "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"

Step1: Tap a row in `RootViewController` will push to `detailsViewController`, tap button in detailsViewController to show a `popOverController`, it worked!

Step2: Tap backButton will pop to `RootViewController`, do Step1 again, Crashed!

Below code will print the window's description all right:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.view.window);
}
```

Button's action Step1 will print the window, Step2 will print nil:

```
- (void)btn_click:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.view.window);
    [self._popOver presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

So, what I was missing?

Answer (score 0):

not much to go on here, but it sounds like your navigation controller logic is wrong somewhere. I'd probably generate a new basic navigation controller project with a second view controller, make sure you can navigate back and forth with it and compare to your project. If you remove the popover, everything works?

Comment: Hi @user697562, thanks for your reply, actually, I generated a new navigation project, and the problem accorded again. I was using XCode4 and ios4.3 sdk.